# AvalancheJS get input/output id

Tags: avalanche

I would like to get the input/output id that is shown in https://avascan.info:

[image]

I could not find any way to get this. There is a `getUTXOID` function but it does not give the same id. (It would give `xrwoWWtWPq4oEAVPRVAQWLCQrdhLeGV5ds4PciC5AnekC6A3r` in my example.) I also don't see that in any response of the api.

Any idea how they do it?